# Weblogic Preprosessor in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic, bea

I have some Java code that is currently packaged in the **BEA Workshop for WebLogic Platform**.

My task is to migrate the structure of the project (without actually touching the code) to a maven structure to be packaged from command line (or from eclipse m2e).

Problem is, the code has some annotations like this:

```
    @WebService(serviceName = "Cancelacion", targetNamespace =
            "http://www.banamex.com.mx/OtorgamientoPension/cancelacion")
    @WLHttpTransport(contextPath = "OtorgamientoPension", serviceUri =
            "cancelacion", portName = "cancelacionSOAP")
    @Policies({
            @Policy(uri="policy:Wssp1.2-Wss1.0-X509-Basic256.xml", direction = Policy.Direction.inbound),
    })
public class CancelacionPortImpl implements CancelacionPort {
    ...
}
```

That create some configuration inside the war (a mysterious meta-inf **inside** the web-inf and plenty of xml).

Please notice the `@Policies` which is from a WebLogic library. It creates some security-related config and that's (alongside the ws stuff) is what i want to generate.

Is there a way to process this from maven?

**EDIT**

So far I have tried with the weblogic-maven-plugin. It didn't work (also, due to internal policies, the not-so-straightforward way of installing this plugin is not an option).

I'm trying to find a vague reference a co-worker gave me about certain **"jtools"** compiler... but can't find anything that comes with that name and have some relation with WebLogic.

So the `@Policies` annotation is still a problem.

Right now I'm looking for a eclipse-plugin that does this, based on the premise that was the IDE who process that annotations.

---

For the wsdl issue, I find out that the namespace definition whas wrong. I corrected it and now it's working. I used the **jaxb2-maven-plugin** because I have no knowledge of **jaxws-maven-plugin** and I already had the config of the former.

Comment: Webservice you should take a look at javaws-maven-plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'll take a look, thanks. But one of the issues is the Policies annotation, which is from a weblogic library, I'll edit the question to make an emphasis in this one.

Comment: What's the motive of the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need some Weblogic classes on your classpath. Short of uploading these to your own private Maven repository, you might consider checking out the [Oracle Maven repository](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_and_the_oracle) to find the Weblogic artifacts you need. Since these are likely container-provided jars (i.e. you don't need to package them in your war), you'll want to define them with a scope of "provided" in your dependencies, e.g. `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Oracle Maven repository. I'll take a look. Thanks.